# Is there a pattern to addition of primesFactored numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

So every rational number can written with primes as so

```
[//2, //3, //5, //7, //11, //13, ...]

1 = [] 
2 = [1] = 2^1
3 = [0,1] = 3^1
4 = [2] = 2^2
5 = [0,0,1] = 5^1
6 = [1,1] = 2^1 * 3^1
30 = [1,1,1] = 2^1 * 3^1 * 5^1 
7! =  [4,2,1,1] =  2^4 * 3^2 * 5^1 * 7^1 
.25 = [-2] = 2^-1 
.333.. = [0,-1] = 3^-1
```

etc..

The advantage of this is all multiplication of numbers are simple additions

```
5 * 4 = 20 === [0,0,1] + [2] = [2,0,1]
```

and all divisions are simple subtractions

```
5 / 4 = 1.25 === [0,0,1] - [2] = [-2,0,1]
```

My question is if there's a way to add these "basePrime" number without transforming them into their original number?

aka if

```
30! = [26, 14, 7, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

what is `30! + 1` ?

the addition seems extremely random

```
> 1 + 2 = 3

[] + [1] = [0,1]

> 5 + 3 = 8

[0,0,1] + [0,1] = [3]

5040 + 4 = 5044

[4,2,1,1] + [2] = [2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

Comment: Short answer. No. Sorry.

Comment: You are touching the big mysteries of prime decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no *known* pattern. Only a rather obvious one: let $v_p(n)$ be the multiplicity of $p$ in $n$, that is, $v_p(n)=\max\{r\in\Bbb Z:p^r\mid n\}$. Then 
$$v_p(n+m)\begin{cases}=\min\{v_p(n),v_p(m)\}\text{ if }v_p(n)\neq v_p(m)\\ \ge v_p(n)\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Goldbach conjecture, twin primes conjecture, and surely more like those, are still conjectures. And probably they would be theorems if there were a pattern like the one you are looking for.

If you found a pattern, you should reegister your achievement and publish it. You would become rich and famous. In the $30$th century, the humankind would remember you as a great mathematician.

Maybe, even credit cards wouldn't be safe anymore... So hire some bodyguards.